# Rails 4 : How to translate devise view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, rails-i18n

I used devise to manage authentication in my web application. Now i want to translate the view in french. So first i've install [devise I18n](https://github.com/tigrish/devise-i18n).

Then i generate the view : `rails g devise:views:locale fr` because i need to customize some texts. 
But when i reload my webapp. I have also restarted it.Labels are translated but links are not translated. In my "Sign Up" page for instance, i have "Log In" and "Didn't receive confirmation instructions?" links are still in English.
Thank you for help.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, not all devise views are fully localized. The links that are not translated in your form come from the partial `devise/shared/_links.html.erb` and they are hard-coded there.
You'll have to extract those strings manually into a locale file.

Answer (score 3):

Hello fellow Frenchman

I suggest you visit :
[devise-i18n github page](https://github.com/tigrish/devise-i18n)

They advice you to edit the config/locales/devise.fr.yml page
where you will be able to edit the translation.

Hope this helps